# Use system date as filenames for files being compared

Tags: c#

I have a C# program that compares two existing csv files and outputs any changes as a new csv.

In the code, you can define which csv files to compare. Each day the csv files are saved in a folder as e.g. bags_02-03-2015.

I need to be able to set the filenames in the code so as to compare a csv file with today's date in the filename with a csv file with yesterday's date in the filename.

E.g.

```
  public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            string fileName1 = "C:\\Users\\Example\\bags_(*TODAYSDATE).csv";
            string fileName2 = "C:\\Users\\Example\\bags_(*YESTERDAYSDATE).csv";
            string fileName3 = "C:\\Users\\Example\\bagcompared.csv";

...
```

Can anyone show me what I should be doing? I am somewhat new to C# so please be gentle.

Many thanks!

Comment: It's C#, not C++ or C...

Comment: you should look at `string.format`.

Answer (score 3):

A simple search should have net you your answer:

```
string fileName1 = "C:\\Users\\Example\\bags_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + ".csv";
string fileName2 = "C:\\Users\\Example\\bags_" + DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + ".csv";
string fileName3 = "C:\\Users\\Example\\bagcompared.csv";
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx